# Getting an AttributeError constantly in fetching from an Entry Widget. How to fix this?

Tags: tkinter, widget, fetch, tkinter-entry, getattribute

*Here's the code*

```
from tkinter import*

win = Tk()

win.title('My application')

e = Entry(win).pack()

def click():

    label = Label(win, text = 
            "Hello" + 
            e.get()).pack()

button = Button(win, text = 
        'Enter your name', 
        command = 
        'click').pack()

win.mainloop()
```

*When I enter a name and click the button I created I end up with an error like,*
*"* **Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'** *".*

*Can anybody please tell me why am I keep getting this Attribute error and how can I fix this? By the way, I'm a beginner who is trying to learn the basics.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `e = Entry(win).pack()` to

```
e = Entry(win)
e.pack()
```

This is because `e = Entry(win).pack()` returns `None` and hence the error.

Hope this helped you.

Cheers

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much ! Finally I got that bug.